# kotlin Unresolved reference for only one inherited method in delegation

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, delegates, kotlin

I have a kotlin class which provides some delegates through methods.
When compiling everything, i get the error

> Error:(121, 30) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: stringSet

Note that all other methods are working just fine and it does compile every other occurence of this method

Here is a snippet of  the class providing the delegates:

```
//Compiles and can be accessed
protected fun int(default: Int? = null, jsonName: String? = null, jsonObject: JsonObject = configJson)
        = JsonProperty({it?.asInt}, jsonName, jsonObject, default.toStringOrNull())

//compiles, but can't be accessed in one class
    protected fun stringSet(jsonName: String? = null, jsonObject: JsonObject = configJson, default: Set<String>? = null): JsonProperty<MutableSet<String>> {
    return JsonProperty<MutableSet<String>>({ _json ->
        if(_json == null) return@JsonProperty null
        else {
            return@JsonProperty CustomMutableSet<String>({ _json.asJsonArray.map { it.asString }.toMutableSet() },
                    {
                        if (!contains(it)) {
                            val changed = !_json.asJsonArray.contains(it.toJsonPrimitive())
                            _json.asJsonArray.add(it)
                            rewriteConfig()
                            changed
                        } else false
                    },
                    {
                        val changed = _json.asJsonArray.contains(it.toJsonPrimitive())
                        _json.asJsonArray.remove(it.toJsonPrimitive())
                        rewriteConfig()
                        changed
                    }).also { toReturn ->
                default?.toMutableSet()?.let {
                    it.removeAll(toReturn)
                    toReturn.addAll(it)
                }
            }
        }

    }, jsonName, jsonObject, "[]")
}
```

This use case compiles:

```
abstract class ElementInfo<T: Element> : Config {

    val input: ElementCollection<T>

    constructor(input: ElementCollection<T>, internal_id: String, arrayIdentifier: String = "primaryElements") : super(input.data, arrayIdentifier, { it -> it.get("internal_id").asString == internal_id }) {
        this.input = input
        this.internal_id = internal_id
    }

    constructor(input: ElementCollection<T>, init: ElementInfo<T>.() -> Unit) : super(){
        this.input = input
        init()
        initDefaults()
    }

    open val tags by stringSet()
    open val genre by stringSet()
    open val fullname by string()
    open var title by string()
    open var artist by stringSet()
    open var featured_Artist by stringSet()
    open var original_Artist by stringSet()
    open var remix_Artist by stringSet()
    open val origin by stringSet()
    open var storage_location by string()
    open var internal_id by string()

}
```

And this doesn't (this class is used in a unit test)

```
class FileConfig : Config("simpleConf.json"){
  var testString by string(default = "hi")
  var testInt by int(1)
  var testBoolean by boolean(true)

//still everything fine
  val deep by jsonObject(default = JsonObject())
  var deepString by string(default = "deep", jsonObject = deep)
  var deepInt by int(default = 3, jsonObject = deep)
  var deepBoolean by boolean(default = true, jsonObject = deep, jsonName = "deepdeep")

  //This does not get compiled
  val testStringSet by stringSet()


  var configArray by jsonArray()
  var configObject by jsonObject()


}
```

Comment: Does it happen when you compile your code in the IDE? Does a command-line Gradle build pass?

Comment: i tried it, but it looks like it needs some ressources which IDEA provides (the kotlin plugin) which is not accesible from CLI

Comment: That looks very weird. If you open code completion after `by` before `stringSet`, do you have it there? What if you copy and paste identifier from declaration to the usage? Sometimes, you know, you have a letter that looks the same but isn't, like English `e` and Russian `е`.